# Which substrates will undergo an E2 reaction to give a (Z) alkene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, elimination, stereoselectivity

**What I do know:** E2 reactions are concerted and have an anti-coplanar transition state, where the leaving group and the hydrogen being abstracted have a dihedral angle of 180 degrees.

**What I don't understand**: A does not have a halogen that acts as a leaving group. B has two halogens (bromine and fluorine). Thus, how do I determine the substrate(s), if any, that will undergo E2?

[image]

Comment: A has a mesylate that is every bit as good a leaving group as a halogen. In B is there a proton with a dihedral angle of 180 to a halogen?

Comment: I would say that it's possible thath both of them could undergo an E2 step. A has the mesylate group that acts like an halogen. B in one of its conformation (may be not the stablest one) has an hydrogen atom in anti-coplanar. 
To choose between F and Br: Br is a better LG than F. To remove an F atom you need very strong conditions

Comment: Be careful with the CIP rules in determining the E/Z assignment. While Br is the better leaving group, configurationally, does it matter whether HBr or HF is lost?